# Fit HTML table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table that looks like this
[image]

using this code:

#### Embeddings Settings

Id:
      
         category1:
         
            None
         
      
      
         category2:
         
            None
         
      
      Reset embeddings

and CSS class form-element:

.form-element {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
  }

So it looks good.
I would like to add 1 checkbox and make the form looks like this :

[image]

The problem is when I try to add new column with a checkbox:
[image]

using this code (just adding a checkbox input):

```css
.form-element {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="form-query-settings">
    <label for="embeddings_weights_form" class="form-label">
        <h3>Embeddings Settings</h3></label>
    <form id="embeddings_weights_form" class="form-settings">
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="id_slider">Id:</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="id_slider" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="id" readonly="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="category1_slider">category1:</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="category1_slider" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="category1_output" readonly="">
            <select id="category1Query" class="query-form-class">
                <option value="None">None</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-element">
                <label for="filterbycategory1">Filter by: </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="filterbycategory1" class="query-form-class">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="category2_slider">category2:</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="category2_slider" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="category2_output" readonly="">
            <select id="category2Query" class="query-form-class">
                <option value="None">None</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-element">
                <label for="filterbycategory2">Filter by: </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="filterbycategory2" class="query-form-class">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="reset-button" class="form-element">Reset embeddings</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I solve it?
I tried to add auto instead of the 1fr in the css file, but it made another bad view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-items: center;` to `.form-control` class.